# Pythonic mapping of an array (Beginner)

Tags: python, arrays

I've got a question related to a beginner Python snippet I've written to introduce myself to the language. It's an admittedly trivial early effort, but I'm still wondering how I could have written it more elegantly.

The program outputs NATO phoenetic readable versions of an argument, such "H2O" -> "Hotel 2 Oscar", or (lacking an argument) just outputs the whole alphabet. I mainly use it for calling in MAC addresses and IQNs, but it's useful for other phone support too.

Here's the body of the relevant portion of the program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

nato = {
"a": 'Alfa',
"b": 'Bravo',
"c": 'Charlie',
"d": 'Delta',
"e": 'Echo',
"f": 'Foxtrot',
"g": 'Golf',
"h": 'Hotel',
"i": 'India',
"j": 'Juliet',
"k": 'Kilo',
"l": 'Lima',
"m": 'Mike',
"n": 'November',
"o": 'Oscar',
"p": 'Papa',
"q": 'Quebec',
"r": 'Romeo',
"s": 'Sierra',
"t": 'Tango',
"u": 'Uniform',
"v": 'Victor',
"w": 'Whiskey',
"x": 'Xray',
"y": 'Yankee',
"z": 'Zulu',
}

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    for n in nato.keys():
            print nato[n]
else:
    # if sys.argv[1] == "-i" # TODO
    for char in sys.argv[1].lower():
            if char in nato:
                    print nato[char],
            else: print char,
```

As I mentioned, I just want to see suggestions for a more elegant way to code this.
My first guess was to use a list comprehension along the lines of `[nato[x] for x in sys.argv[1].lower() if x in nato]`, but that doesn't allow me to output any non-alphabetic characters.
My next guess was to use `map`, but I couldn't format any lambdas that didn't suffer from the same corner case.

Any suggestions? Maybe something with first-class functions? Messing with Array's guts?
This seems like it could almost be a Code Golf question, but I feel like I'm just overthinking :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dict [get with default](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)  perhaps?

```
for char in sys.argv[1].lower():
  print nato.get(char, char) # try to get nato[char] otherwise return char
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the above suggestion and a generator expression to do it all in one line

```
print ' '.join(nato.get(c,c) for c in sys.argv[1].lower())
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a compact way of building your list:

```
import sys
import string

NATO = '''Alpha Bravo Charlie Delta Echo Foxtrot Golf Hotel India Juliet
Kilo Lima Mike November Oscar Papa Quebec Romeo Sierra Tango Uniform
Victor Whiskey X-Ray Yankee Zulu'''.split()

nato = dict(zip(string.lowercase,NATO))

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    for n in nato:
        print n,nato[n]
else:
    for char in sys.argv[1].lower():
        print nato.get(char,char)
```

Comment: The way you initialize the nato dict, there is an implicit requirement that the words in the NATO string are in alphabetical order (I know they already are). I would prefer something like `nato = dict( (word[0].lower(), word) for word in NATO). Your 'sierra' is also lower-case.